# multiple checkbox dropdown onchange() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Multiple Drop Down Checkbox not working properly. always getting first parameter as `undefined` and always `onchange` getting first checkbox value.

```
<select name="multicheckbox[]" multiple="multiple" class="4colactive" onchange="selectsearch(this.selected,'property_type',this.value);">
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
</select>
```

my java script code which call when `onchange` dropdown.

```js
function selectsearch(val2,val1,state_id){
    var title=state_id;
    alert(val2);
    alert(val1);
    alert(state_id);
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/property/propertysearch',
        data: {'title':title,'name':val1,'status':val2 }, // change this to send js object
        type: "post",
        success: function(data){
            //document.write(data); just do not use document.write
            console.log(data);
            document.getElementById('search').innerHTML = data; 
            document.getElementById('search').style.display  = 'block'; 
            document.getElementById("search1").style.display = 'none';
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Fail")
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to use `oninput` rather than `onchange` for `<select>` inputs.

```
<select oninput="console.log('test')">
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
  <option value="CA">California</option>
  <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
  <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
  <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
</select>
```

Comment: how to call selectsearch(this.selected,'property_type',this.value) function with these parameter. can you please edit the code and show me!